# Possible Values of $\dim(Null(L))$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

can you please help me check this question

down vote
favorite

can you please explain this question to me? Thanks

Question : Suppose that $L: \Bbb{R}^4 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation.

a) what are the possible values of $\dim(Null(L))$?

b) For each possible value of $\dim(Null(L))$ provide an example linear transformation $L: \Bbb{R}^4 \to \Bbb{R}^2$  so that $\dim(Null(L))$ is equal to that value.

Attempt :

a) the possible values i got are 4, 3, 2

b) i don't understand part b very well

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L : E \to F$ and $\dim(E)<\infty$  $\dim(F)<\infty$ then 
$$
\dim(E)=\dim(Ker(L))+\dim(Im(L))
$$
This give the first values of a) because $\dim(Im(L)\leq 2$ and $\dim(E)=4$

b)
If $\dim(Ker(L))=4$ then $L=0$.

for the example of $\dim(Ker(E))=3$ we put 
$$
L(x,y,z,t)=(x,0)
$$
here $Ker(L)=\{(0,y,z,t) ; \textrm{such that } y,z,t\in \mathbb{R} \}$, so of dimension 3.

If we consider now $$L(x,y,z,t)=(x,y,0,0)$$
then $Ker(L)=\{(0,0,z,t) ; \textrm{such that } z,t\in \mathbb{R} \}$, so of dimension 2.